# Why aren't the rows being deleted by this code ? ( Flask-SQLAlchemy )

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is a part of my code :
I am trying to delete all the rows that match the criteria instructor=chosen_student.
Now I know for a fact this query is working. But the rows are just NOT removed from the table ?!?!

```py
class Alert(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = "alerts"

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    alert = db.Column(db.String(4096))
    CW_class = db.Column(db.String(612))
    instructor = db.Column(db.String(612))  #instructor = username !
    date = db.Column(db.String(612))
    importDate = db.Column(db.String(612))

input = request.form.get('student')
list = input.split('-')
action = list[0]
chosen_student = list[1]
delete_q = Alert.query.filter_by(instructor=chosen_student).delete()
msg = str(delete_q)
db.session.commit
```

When I run this code, printing `delete_q will output '2'`, which is correct: there are 2 records that match the selection criteria(`instructor=chosen_student`). But when running a select query afterward, the 2 rows are NOT deleted...

Does anyone have a clue why?

Comment: `db.session.commit` is a method, you need to call it: `db.session.commit()`

Comment: Ahhhhhh... SO simple !
Will you believe I was struggling with that for hours ?
Constantly changing the query, but totally overlooking those (simple) parentheses...

Thank you SO much !

Comment: Happens to us all from time-to-time!

Answer (score 2):

```
db.session.commit()
```

([pay attention to parentheses](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.commit))

You can use any linters (such as pylint or flake8) to avoid such typos in the future.